# Inconsistent answers from Play Store (V2 billing code)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using this for in-app managed items - has to be V2 billing code for now for compatibility with old OSs.

Code all worked OK - until now. However using a test email address it seems to have got in a muddle.
 - on a RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS to find out about previous purchases the request goes through OK, is responded to OK, but in the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGE there are no previous transactions listed. Fair enough - there had been a purchase, but it had been cancelled.
 - but, when trying to purchase Play Store pops up a dialogue saying "you already own this item", and will not allow it to be purchased. 
 - worse still, if one clicks on 'Details ...' in the Play Store dialogue to find out about the purchase, Play Store crashes.

This would seem therefore to be a Play Store / Google servers issue. Has anyone seen this before, and how do you get around it?

There are some other questions around this, but no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to clear this inconsistency is under settings >> applications to clear the caches for Play Store and Play Store services.